# Symfony throwing TransformationFailedException on DateTime field

Tags: symfony, orm, doctrine-orm, symfony-2.1, formbuilder

I'm new to Symfony and I'm having some trouble rendering a twig-form filled with data from database. The entity is fetched and mapped correctly by Doctrine.

It always throws a **TransformationFailedException** in **DateTimeToStringTransformer::reverseTransform($value)** where $value should be a string - but it is already a DateTime...

My entity has the date-field defined like this:

```
/**
 * @var \DateTime
 * @ORM\Column(type="datetime", nullable=false)
 * @Validator\DateTime(message = "validator.invalidType.date")
 * @Validator\NotBlank(message = "validator.createDate.notBlank")
 */
private $createDate;
```

In the form class it says:

```
$builder->add('createDate', null, array('read_only' => true));
```

I've been debugging with xdebug and it appears, that the field is already resolved "correctly" to a DateTime-instance. So I don't get, why Symfony is trying to convert again a string into a DateTime-object.

Comment: instead of `null`, replace your second argument with `'date'`. I'm not very enthousiast about the symfony's guessing.

Comment: just as simple as that... thanks a lot!